# Gradient of $2$-norm inside absolute value

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, subgradient

> Compute the gradient of $$ z = | \lVert L x \lVert_2 - P | $$ where $ x \in \mathbb{C}^N $ and $ P \in \mathbb{R}_{+} $.

First, I make $ a = \lVert L x \lVert_2 - P $. Also, since $ | a | $ is non-differentiable, its subdifferential is defined as 
$$ \partial z = \begin{cases}
                    -1, & \text{if}\ a < 0 \\
                    1, & \text{if}\ a > 0 \\
                    (-1,1), & \text{if}\ a = 0 \\
                \end{cases}
$$

Furthermore, 
$$
\partial a = x^H L^H L (\partial a)
$$
On the other hand, $ | a | = \max \{ a, -a\} $. Thus,

$$
\partial z = \max \{\partial a, -\partial a\}
=  \max \{ x^H L^H L (\partial a), -x^H L^H L (\partial a) \}
$$

The sub-gradient therefore is given by

$$
\nabla_x z = x^H L^H L \circ sign(x^H L^H L)
$$

However, I am not sure of this result. Are the procedure and the result correct?

Comment: Why are you using the $\ell_1$-norm here? $\|Lx\|_2-P$ is a scalar. You just need a simple absolute value.

Comment: Hi Michael. You are right but it may not change much the problem.

Comment: Agreed, it will be the same.

Comment: Partition space into two regions. Then compute the gradient in each region.